# placing a text box inside the silverlight data grid column header

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

how to add a text box inside the silverlight data grid column  header?

so that i can use the text boxes for the filteration purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
       <TextBox Text="{Binding YourTargetProperty}"/>
</sdk:DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

The following article deals with the Filtering and Sorting.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83906/Silverlight-4-Datagrid-Sorting-Grouping-Filtering-.aspx

Comment: but how will u get the column details  from which the user is firing filter event