# DataGrid column header with a text box for filtering

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I'm having a bit of problems creating a `DataGrid` with a header label AND a text box (at this point I'm not even entirely sure this is possible).

Here's what I want to do:
I need to dynamically create a table (the number of columns can and will change, so the grid needs to be created dynamically and cannot use bindings specified in the XAML code or similar). All the columns however will always be text columns.

Because those will be text columns, I'd like to add a text box to each header to enable simple filtering of the data in the `DataGrid`. I don't want to add extra text fields to OTHER parts of the Silverlight page, as I want to keep things as compact as possible. Also, since the number of columns is dynamic, adding a large number of text boxes above the `DataGrid` wouldn't look too good either. ;)

Also, if possible, I'd like to keep a label in each header to display the names of the columns as well.

So far I've tried adding the a `TextBox` as the `Header` of a `DataGridTextBoxColumn` but when I do that in a very simple Silverlight project, the whole `DataGrid` won't show up.

Please help.

EDIT:
I saw the answer to this question: [placing a text box inside the silverlight data grid column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022753/placing-a-text-box-inside-the-silverlight-data-grid-column-header)

However, the answer itself didn't give me much to go on (the example is too short, and I'm not too good with XAML yet), and the code on CodePlex just adds extra fields to the Silverlight page. None of it tackles the problem of dynamically creating the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's what I did that solved my issue...
I had to use a `Style` to achieve the functionality of having an extra text box inside each column header and filling out the `Tag` property of each thus created `TextBox` to later find out which column has been changed.

Comment: i have your problem and i don't know how to find out which column has been changed?what do you fill your textboxes tag with?

Comment: Since you're using a `Style`, you can't type in a fixed `Tag`. That would be pointless. I used `Tag="{Binding}"`, thus you should get the reference to whatever you put in your column header.

Comment: Shaamaan:Thanks,but i hope i could get refrence to coulmn Name,because the column Headers are persian and i need english names,is there any way to bind column Name to tag?

Comment: Create a custom class to hold the header data (create any properties you need). Make sure to override `ToString` to display whatever the actual display name is. Then you can create a Tag binding `{Binding YourHeaderPropertyName}`.